# Fomating content like url preview

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create my own url preview. Like facebook shows. Dont want to use readymade script.

Here I go:

```
echo "<a href="; echo $url;  echo"/>"; echo $title_display; echo "</a>"; //show url and title description    
echo "</br>";
echo "<img src='"; echo $logo; echo "'height='84' width='66' >"; // shows image on the page
$content = plaintext($data); 
$Preview = trim_display(100,$content); //to Show first 100 char of the web page as preview
echo $Preview;   
echo " <a href="; echo $url;  echo " target=_blank />"; echo "See More"; echo "</a>"; // See more link to go on that page
```

But here formatting is not appropriate.

How can I show entire things in one box whic contains.

1. first title desc and it's url i.e. `echo "<a href="; echo $url;  echo"/>"; echo $title_display; echo "</a>"; //show url and title description`
2. Below it Image on left side of box (can take div for that)
3. Preview i.e. small 100 char description on right side of image.

Exactly same way as image preview shown by facebook when URL is entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all ready a better written block. You dont have to use that much of echo's if you can do it with 1.

```
echo '<div id="box">
   <a href="'.$url.'">'.$title_display.'</a>'; //show url and title description    
   echo'<br />
   <div>
      <img src="'.$logo.'" height="84" width="66" style="float:left;">'; // shows image on the page
      $content = plaintext($data); 
      $Preview = trim_display(100,$content); //to Show first 100 char of the web page as preview
      echo '<p style="float:left;">'.$Preview.'</p>';   
   echo '</div>
   <a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank" />See More</a>'; // See more link to go on that page 
echo '</div>';
```

You can set a `div` around it with an `id` **(box)**, that way you can change the look with **css**. 
And a `div` around the `image` and `$preview`. 
a `float:left;` on the `image` and the `<p>` around `$preview`

***Update after comment:***

To edit the complete box, you can use

```
#box{ height: .. ; width: .. ; }   /*For the height and width of the complete box */
/* float:left; in the css file is better than inline code like in the example */
#box img { float:left;}  /* for the image */
#box p { float:left; width:300px;}   /* for the p tag */

|--------------------------#box (400px)--------------------------| 
|                                                                |
| |---------------|   |---------------------------------------|  |
| |               |   |                                       |  |
| |     IMG       |   |           <p>                         |  |
| |               |   |           float:left;                 |  |
| |  float:left   |   |           width:300px;                |  |
| |               |   |                                       |  |
| |               |   |                                       |  |
| |---------------|   |---------------------------------------|  |
|                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Because the #box is 400px, the image is smaller than 100px, can the $preview be like 300px. 
 and because **100 + 300 = 400px** (with the `float:left;`) it should fit next to each other.

You can create a gab between the image and text `with margin-right:5px;` on the **image** OR `margin-left:5px;` on the `<p>`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pD8PX/1/)**

Comment: @C: thatnks a lot. I tested this. But i think it needs css for correct view. Can you please tell me what kind of stuff I should include in css?

Comment: you should give the the image and the `p` some `width`, so it fits inside the `#box`

Comment: Click on the demo, you can see that the text is next to the image

Comment: The best answer I got ever. But When I changed my php code. Still it shows scatters. investigating

Comment: Thats what i like the most about programming, trying trying and achieving! practice `html, css and php` ;)

Comment: Yes, about to solution! can you please tell me how to give small gap between image and <p> ?

Comment: with `margin-right:5px;` on the image OR `margin-left:5px;` on the `<p>`